# firebase : sending email verification during signup

Tags: javascript, firebase

I tested that user is added to database but she never receive any email : what's wrong below (took it from doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users but something missing )

```
function SignUp() {
    let promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value); 
    promise.catch(
        e => alert(e.message)
    );

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
      // Email sent.
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting until the sign-up is complete. To do that you can use the `then` part of the promise returned by `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

So:

```
let promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value); 
promise.then(
   userCredential => userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification()
}).catch(
    e => alert(e.message)
);
```